# Selecting the first element from a group of ids in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_transact_id int NOT NULL,
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_amount int NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_date date NOT NULL,
    the_debt_flag varchar(6)
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('900004','LMUS01', '200', '2/12/2019','NORMAL'), 
       ('900002','LMUS01', '200', '2/11/2019','NORMAL'), 
       ('900005','LMUS01', '300', '2/13/2019','RESCHE'), 
       ('900001','LMUS02', '100', '2/10/2019','NORMAL'), 
       ('900003','LMUS02', '150', '2/12/2019','NORMAL')
```

And I want the first element from each debt id sorted in descend by the transact number but that its flag it's not 'RESCHE'.

This is the expected output:

```
the_debt_transact_id    the_debt_id    the_amount    the_debt_date    the_debt_flag 
900004                  LMUS01         200           2/12/2019        NORMAL
900003                  LMUS02         150           2/12/2019        NORMAL
```

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(the_debt_id) 
FROM my_table 
WHERE the_debt_id IN ('LMUS01','LMUS02') 
AND the_debt_flag <> 'RESCHE' 
ORDER BY the_debt_transact_id DESC
```

But it returns me

> syntax error near FROM

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select *something*.  For all the columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (the_debt_id) t.*
FROM my_table t
WHERE the_debt_id IN ('LMUS01','LMUS02') AND the_debt_flag <> 'RESCHE'
ORDER BY the_debt_idl, the_debt_transact_id DESC ;
```

Note that the `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY` need to be consistent.

Comment: Great @Gordon Linoff! Thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: The error is somewhat surprising though as `select from my_table` (omitting all columns) is actually valid in Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Totally agree, but it is an error:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=91b372b42ea7737b486f50b1db00110a.  Just a parsing error, probably, that doesn't get caught because it is not an obvious test case.